# clone rectangles and custom paths on drag

Tags: svg, raphael, jquery-svg

Couldn't any solution on other sites about how to clone rectangles and other custom paths on drag in raphael js.

I am able to clone circle and the same is not working for other paths. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Editor</title>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/connector.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function ()
            {
                var paper = new Raphael(Raphael("container", "100%", "100%"));
                var sidebar = paper.rect(0, 43.5, 69, 620);
                var rect = paper.rect(10, 50, 51, 41, 5).attr({stroke: '#6DAACA', 'stroke-width': 1, fill: '#D6F2FC'});
                var circle1 = paper.circle(35, 145, 25).attr({fill: '#fff', 'stroke-width': 2, stroke: '#399324'});
                var circle2 = paper.circle(35, 225, 25).attr({fill: '#fff', 'stroke-width': 4, stroke: '#9E2F3C'});
                var circle3 = paper.circle(35, 310, 25).attr({fill: '#fff', 'stroke-width': 4, stroke: '#D5C096'});
                var Customrect = paper.path("M25 370 L10 370 L10 411 L25 411 L25 370 L61 370 L61 411 L25 411");

                // circle clonning
                paper.set(circle1);
                var clone_handler = function () {
                    var x = this.clone();
                    x.drag(move, start, up);
                };
                var start = function (x, y, event) {
                    this.ox = this.attr("cx");
                    this.oy = this.attr("cy");
                },
                        move = function (dx, dy) {
                            this.attr({
                                cx: this.ox + dx,
                                cy: this.oy + dy
                            });
                        },
                        up = function () {
//                            this.animate({
//                                r: 20,
//                                opacity: .8
//                            }, 500, ">");
                        };
                circle1.mousemove(clone_handler);
                circle2.mousemove(clone_handler);
                circle3.mousemove(clone_handler);
                rect.mousemove(clone_handler);



              //Custom Rectangle or Path

               paper.set(customRect);
            var clone_handler3 = function () {
                var z = this.clone();
                z.drag(move3, start3, up3);
            };
            var start3 = function (x, y, event) {
                this.crx = this.attr("x");
                this.cry = this.attr("y");
            },
                    move3 = function (dx, dy) {
                        this.attr({
                            x: this.crx + dx,
                            y: this.cry + dy
                        });
                    },
                    up3 = function () {
                    };
            customRect.mousemove(clone_handler3);
        };
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                <h1 id="title">Editor</h1>
                <div id="footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It depends what you mean. It should clone it fine. Are you saying the clone doesn't work ? The drag won't work as you are setting cx/cy which isn't a valid attribute on a rect (you would have to either amend x,y on a rect, or for a generic solution use transforms which can work on any elements and some containers).

Comment: @Ian How about custom path I have created? How do I clone that?

Comment: clone() will clone any svg element afaik. Same thing applies though, if you want to be able to drag it, you will have to change its x,y attributes (rather than cx,cy or apply a translate transform which is more standard).

Comment: clone() is not working on custom path on drag and transform is moving the original element.

Answer (score 1):

The clone works fine. There's just lots of bugs you need to work through. You need to remove all of the other clutter for SO questions, just place concise examples on a jsfiddle.

If you do a clone on a mousemove, you end up with lots of clones, not just one, every slight movement. Thats probably not what you want. Create it on a click or some single event, rather than mousemoves.

Make sure the path is filled.

Move with a transform and not with x,y

Fix the initialisation of Raphael, eg not this..var paper = new Raphael(Raphael("container", "100%", "100%"));

Comment: Ok fine I will try to clone on click but atleast tell me if I can drag around the element after clone-transform? because the rest of elements are cloned on mousemove with only one clone then how come it will create so many clones on mouse move?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you aren't creating more clones ? As they will appear on top of each other its hard to tell, but the logic suggests every delta mousemove will create a new clone if I'm not missing something. You should be able to transform the path fine. A translate string eg 't100,100' should highlight this

Comment: Actually, it may not create more clones if the clone hides the new one in time and is in the exact same position capturing mouse events I guess, but its a bit of a strange setup like that, and prone to errors.

Comment: why do you think its a strange setup? Element.clone() is a method from raphael docs, I am not creating anything new here. There should be a way to create clone() on drag and move it around freely for custom elements(path string).

Comment: Its just prone to errors to create objects based on inaccurate input from users, users aren't specifically doing anything.

Comment: What do you mean by inaccurate input from user? I haven't specified any thing about users in my question. Please do read the question properly before commenting. Its just getting more confusing

Comment: I have read the question, and I wasted more time than necessary, because 1) relevant code wasn't isolated. This meant I had to do this myself. 2) As soon as you do this, you realised strange things start happening, placing clones on top of each other the same colour, with a drag on one. Always isolate to a concise question, and strip ALL stuff that isn't relevant to the question.